# MySQL Query works in phpMyAdmin but not in php script

Tags: php

I have a query that I have run in phpMyAdmin and it returns results but if I cut and paste the query into a php script on a webpage the query seems to run but nothing is shown on the page. It also doesn't finish loading the page. The page ends where my query starts. Is it possible that the execute time for a web based query takes too long versus a query run through phpMyAdmin?  Here is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT tblCertificates.WebReportedDt, tblInsHeader.name1, tblInsHeader.name2, tblQuotes.certnum, tblQBalloons.regnum
FROM ((`tblQuotes`
INNER JOIN `tblInsHeader` ON tblQuotes.insuredid = tblInsHeader.insuredid)
INNER JOIN `tblQBalloons` ON tblQuotes.quoteid = tblQBalloons.quoteid)
INNER JOIN `tblCertificates` ON tblQuotes.quoteid = tblCertificates.QuoteID
WHERE (((tblCertificates.WebReportedDt) IS NOT NULL)AND ((tblCertificates.web) = True) AND tblCertificates.WebReportedDt >= '".$MyDate."')
ORDER BY tblCertificates.WebReportedDt DESC , tblInsHeader.name1, tblQuotes.certnum, tblQBalloons.regnum";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die("Query Timed out");
  while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
extract ($r);
 echo $WebReportedDt." - ".$name1." ".$name2." - ".$certnum." - ".$regnum."<br>";
}
```

The MyDate var is the current date (YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss) in DATETIME format.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your exact PHP code. What you provided is incomplete.

Comment: Is error reporting on? If not, you might just be failing to connect to the database...

Comment: you probably are breaking your PHP code with the quotes and have to escape your quotes or single quotes with backslashes

Comment: Please update your question with your exact php code and mysql query.

Comment: Updated my question with more detailed code.

Comment: @jasper probably not due to `die("Query Timed out");`

Comment: Try to `echo $query` and copypaste it to phpMyAdmin. That will help you spot any possible errors you might have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
Turns out I needed to increase the execution time. 
The query was taking too long and php was timing out.